# How to expand container but stop on a certain size?

Tags: flutter

I have a `Container` that should take all available space, but not more than 500 x 500.

If I put it inside of Flexible or Expanded it will grow to take all the screen. Is there in Flutter something similar to android:maxWidth?

Comment: You'll want to use `Flexible` if your widget is inside a Row/Column

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BoxConstraints` ,

```
    Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: 500.0,
                    maxWidth: 500.0,
                    minHeight: 100.0,
                    minWidth: 100.0),
                child: YourChild(),

                )
```

More info: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/BoxConstraints-class.html